# how to check a line start with foo or bar?

Tags: java, regex

in my case i have a some word like

```
**********menu 1************
gaurav
saurav
amit
avanish


**********menu 2************
gauravqwe
sourav
anit
abhishek
```

**now i want to check item "gaurav" from menu one or menu two.**

if "gaurav" from menu 1 then return true else return false

i m try:

```
class Regex_Test {

    public void checker(String Regex_Pattern){

          Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String Test_String = Input.nextLine();
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Regex_Pattern);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(Test_String);
          System.out.println(m.find());
   }   
}


public class CheckHere {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Regex_Test tester = new Regex_Test();
        tester.checker("^[gsa][amv]"); // Use \\ instead of using \ 
    }
}
```

but it returns true in case of "gauravqwe"
i need expression "string" for the above question
 **Condition** string size is less then 15 character

Comment: Take the time to make your question more precise and your example code more significant. You can edit your question.

Comment: This behavior is right since gauravqwe also starts with ga. What's your question? If you want to use regex to solve this you have to use a different pattern.

Comment: now i want to check item "gaurav" from menu one or menu two.

if "gaurav" from menu 1 then return true else return false

Comment: Where does this strange string come from: "^[gsa][amv]"? Why do you think it helps you in your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta-character word boundaries `\b`

```
\bbgaurav\b
```

---

[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI6jW3/1)

---

References:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: actully i need expression "string" for the above question and string size is  less then 15 character.

Answer (score 0):

## Less than 15 characters

To do this in less than 15 characters you need a regex that looks like this:

```
^gaurav(\r|\Z)
```

This regex is a subset of following answer.

## Description

I'd do it in one pass by building a Regex to grab the menu title of the matching entry. This regex will do the following:

- find `gaurav` in the source string
- return the menu name from the matching section
- if the string does not contain a match then return will be empty

**The Regex**

```
[*]{9,}([^*]*?)[*]{9,}(?:(?![*]{9,}).)*^gaurav(?:\r|\Z)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note this regex uses the following options: case-insensitive, multiline (with ^ and $ matching start and end of line), and dot matches new line (with . matching \n)

**Explanation**

This construct `(?:(?![*]{9,}).)*` is where all the magic happens. This forces the searching to move forward through the string, but does not allow the pattern matching to span multiple `**********` delimited segments.

The `^` and `(?:\n|\Z)` constructs force the regex engine to match a full string, and not just the initial characters. Example: if you're looking for `gaurav` then `gauravqwe` will not be matched.

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [*]{9,}                  any character of: '*' (at least 9 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^*]*?                   any character except: '*' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [*]{9,}                  any character of: '*' (at least 9 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [*]{9,}                  any character of: '*' (at least 9
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  gaurav                   'gaurav'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Z                       before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

**Java Code Example**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[*]{9,}([^*]*?)[*]{9,}(?:(?![*]{9,}).)*^gaurav(?:\\r|\\Z)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Returns**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => **********menu 1************
gaurav
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => menu 1
        )

)
```